# Url.Action MVC3 not recognizing route parameter when building link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, url.action

When adding custom routing constraints to my route parameters I am finding that it is breaking the Url.Action method I use to build my links. If the route constraint is simply a regular expression then the Url.Action method continues to recognize the parameter, however if it is a custom constraint which I define, Url.Action method gives my parameter as a request parameter.

Here is my route definition:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Event",
            "Events/{strDate}",
            new { controller = "Events", action = "Index", strDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") },
            new { strDate = new IsValidDateConstraint() },
            new[] { "MyProject.Controllers" }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "MyProject.Controllers" }
        );
```

The IsValidDateConstraint class inherits from IRouteConstraint and returns true or false if the strDate parameter parses correctly to a DateTime object:

```
public class IsValidDateConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.IncomingRequest)
        {
            DateTime dt = new DateTime();

            if (DateTime.TryParse(values["strDate"].ToString(), out dt))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Using the Url.Action method to build URL's:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Events", new { strDate = ViewBag.CurrentDate.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })
```

The resulting link is: /Events?strDate=2012-08-15

Everything routes correctly if I type in /Events/2012-08-15, it's just that the Url.Action method is not recognizing that strDate is a parameter defined in my route only when I apply my custom routing constraint. If I comment out the custom routing constraint then the Url.Action method maps the URL correctly.

Any ideas on why the Url.Action is not recognizing my route parameter when I have a custom route constraint defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't shown how your `IsValidDateConstraint` looks like but make sure you are doing a culture invariant parsing for the `yyyy-MM-dd` format:

```
public class IsValidDateConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        DateTime date;
        return DateTime.TryParseExact(
            values[parameterName] as string, 
            "yyyy-MM-dd", 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
            DateTimeStyles.None, 
            out date
        );
    }
}
```

Also make sure that this route is placed before the default route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Event",
        "Events/{strDate}",
        new { controller = "Events", action = "Index", strDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") },
        new { strDate = new IsValidDateConstraint() },
        new[] { "MyProject.Controllers" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

also `DateTime.Parse(ViewBag.CurrentDate.ToString())` looks a wee-bit of a WTFkish code. If `ViewBag.CurrentDate` is already a DateTime you could directly write:

```
@Url.Action(
    "Index", 
    "Events", 
    new { 
        strDate = ViewBag.CurrentDate.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") 
    }
)
```

Obviously a much better solution is to use view models:

```
@Url.Action(
    "Index", 
    "Events", 
    new { 
        strDate = Model.CurrentDate.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") 
    }
)
```

---

UPDATE:

Now that you have shown your code the problem comes from the if condition you have put in your constraint:

```
if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.IncomingRequest)
```

When using the `Url.Action` helper this condition is never satisfied. Only when resolving an incoming url. So you will have to remove it if you want this constraint to work with url helpers.

Comment: I've updated my post to include all of the code I use. Keep in mind that this problem is happening for EVERY route constraint I set, not just the ones checking for a valid DateTime string. As for the ViewBag you are right, not sure why I did the double parsing there, but as this is the ONLY variable I need I found it easier to not create a ViewModel. This information is very informative and precise, but the problem is still persisting. Any other thoughts?

Comment: In your constraint you are using `if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.IncomingRequest)`. That's why your code doesn't work. It always returns false when evaluated by the Url.Action helper because that's not an incoming request. Look at the code I have shown in my answer. There's no such `if` condition in my constraint. I have updated my answer to include this information at the end.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I appreciate the help. Thank you!